# Remove apostrophes that are at the ends but not the ones in the middle

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I need to use a binary search tree to count the number of unique words in a file. Words like students and students' would make the count for the word students 2 as plurals are indistinguishable, but don't and dont are separate words. How would I go about this? I am thinking of removing the ending apostrophes of words before adding them into my tree but I'm not sure how to do so without removing all apostrophes, including the ones in the middle of words.

This is the code I am using to add the words into my tree:

```
while(std::cin.get(letter)) { 
if(std::isalpha(letter) || letter == 39) {
    letter = std::tolower(letter);
    word.push_back(letter);
}
else {
    if (word.size() != 0) {
    tree.add(word);
    word.clear();
```

}
}

Comment: The way you are going about getting the input looks convoluted to me.  It would be a lot easier with a simple loop that has `std::cin >> word;`

Comment: You either need to read a line of input into a `std::string` and then use the `.front()` and `.back()` member functions to check the 1st and last char against an apostrophe, OR you need to keep a simple `bool inword;` flag and set to `false` when whitespace is encountered allowing you to check `if (!inword && !isalpha(c)`) to catch the 1st char. at the end of each loop save the current char in a `last` variable which will allow an `if (inword && isspace(c) && !isalpha(last)) { /* delete last char */; inword = false; }`. Using `std::string` simplifies the logic.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to remove all the ending apostrophes from a `std::string`, that can be easily done by using a loop (assuming `word` is not empty):

```
std::string word;
//...
while (!word.empty() && word.back() == '\'')
    word.pop_back();
```

See [std::string::pop_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back).

Comment: Also see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/ends_with